# Sql update query to recalculate sequence of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in re-sequencing the numbers as described in the below example.

```
ID  NAME  SEQ_NUM
---|-----|---------
1    N1     1
2    N1     2
3    N1     3
4    N2     1
5    N2     2
6    N3     1
```

Lets say now if I perform few deletes and updates as below

```
ID  NAME  SEQ_NUM
---|------|-------
1    N1     1
3    N1     4    
4    N2     2
5    N2     3
6    N3     6
```

Now am in an attempt to write an single update query to update the above table to look like below.

```
ID  NAME  SEQ_NUM
---|------|--------
1    N1     1
3    N1     2    
4    N2     1
5    N2     2    
6    N3     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge into the_table
using
(
    select id, 
           name, 
           row_number() over (partition by name order by seq_num) as new_seq_num
    from the_table
) t on (t.id = the_table.id)
when matched then update
   set seq_num = t.new_seq_num;
```

This assumes that `ID` is in fact the PK of the table.